# Use formula to calculate the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(3n-2)z^n}$ for $z = \frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Use $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(n+1)z^n = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}}, n \in \mathbb{C}, |z| < 1$ to calculate the sum of
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(3n-2)z^n}$ for $z = \frac{1}{2}$.

My attempt is to substitute $n$ so that it fits the formula:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {((3n-3)+1)(z^{3n-3})^{\frac{n}{3n-3}}}$, but it seems to me that this doesn't get my any closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $|z|<1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(3n-2)z^n}=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(n+1)z^n}-5\sum_{n=1}^\infty{z^n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
since
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(n+1)z^n = \dfrac{1}{(1-z)^2}}
$
and
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \dfrac{1}{(1-z)^2}
$,
we have

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(an+b)z^n
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(an+a+b-a)z^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(an+a)z^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(b-a)z^n\\
&=a\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)z^n+(b-a)\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\\
&=\dfrac{a}{(1-z)^2}+\dfrac{b-a}{1-z}
\qquad (*)\\
&=\dfrac{a+(b-a)(1-z)}{(1-z)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a+(b-a)-(b-a)z}{(1-z)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{b-(b-a)z}{(1-z)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{b+(a-b)z}{(1-z)^2}
\qquad(**)\\
\end{array}
$

If $z = \frac12$,
this gives,
using $(*)$,
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{an+b}{2^n}
=4a+2(b-a)
=2a+2b
=2(a+b)
$.

If $a=3, b=-2$
this is
$2$.